# Drag child nodes from asp.net tree view and drop it in div

Tags: asp.net, drag-and-drop, treeview

I have an ASP.Net tree view control as this structure:

```
-Category-01
------Product-01
------Product-02
------Product-03
-Category-02
------Product-04
------Product-05
------Product-06
```

and i have a dive beside this tree view, i want to drag product from this tree view and drop it in this div.
Can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution in JQuery UI website.
You can see [here](http://jqueryui.com/droppable/#shopping-cart).